# Does a git clone/push/pull mirror the exact contents of the repos involved?

Tags: git

I wasn't sure how to word the question, so apologies if it's not clear. If you `git clone` a repo that had a bunch of dangling objects, do you clone those?  Same for the opposite.  If you did a `git gc` and pushed that to someone else, does their repo lose anything the `git gc` would have cleaned up?

I would guess that neither of these would occur, but I can't find any documentation on this scenario.

I found [some information](http://progit.org/book/ch4-1.html) that seems to imply that with most protocols `git clone` gives you a clean repo, but if you specify the file using a file path it copies everything.

```
The main reason to specify the file:// prefix is if you want a clean copy of the
repository with extraneous references or objects left out.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Git clone doesn't clone dangling objects.

And your `git gc` will not in any way affect the remote repo when you push to it, unless your push causes dangling objects and then a `git gc` is run on remote to remove those.

Unless....

It was a shared clone ( specified with the `--shared` or `-s` flag) or a local clone (`--local` or `-l`). From the docs:

> -l
>
> When the repository to clone from is on a local machine, this flag
>   bypasses the normal "git aware" transport mechanism and clones the
>   repository by making a copy of **HEAD and everything under objects and
>   refs directories**. The files under .git/objects/ directory are
>   hardlinked to save space when possible. This is now the default when
>   the source repository is specified with /path/to/repo syntax, so it
>   essentially is a no-op option. To force copying instead of hardlinking
>   (which may be desirable if you are trying to make a back-up of your
>   repository), but still avoid the usual "git aware" transport
>   mechanism, --no-hardlinks can be used.
>
> -s
>
> When the repository to clone is on the local machine, instead of
>   using hard links, automatically setup .git/objects/info/alternates to
>   share the objects with the source repository. The resulting repository
>   starts out without any object of its own.
>
> NOTE: this is a possibly dangerous operation; do not use it unless
>   you understand what it does. If you clone your repository using this
>   option and **then delete branches (or use any other git command that
>   makes any existing commit unreferenced) in the source repository, some
>   objects may become unreferenced (or dangling). These objects may be
>   removed by normal git operations (such as git commit) which
>   automatically call git gc --auto**.

So when you do a `git clone /path/to/repo` you are copying the objects ( or creating hardlinks) and you will get the dangling object in this case. In other cases ( using git protocols, ssh, file protocol etc. ) you will never get the dangling objects in the clone.

Look here for how the transport happens - http://progit.org/book/ch9-6.html

Comment: Will a `git pull` pull dangling objects from the remote server?

Comment: Thanks manojlds, read through this a bit last night, gotta dig a little deaper though

Comment: NB that local is inferred unless the path is a url